# Ambiguous column name in Ruby on Rails with SQLite database?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am getting this error in my Rails app:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid in PaymentsController#index

SQLite3::SQLException: ambiguous column name: date: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "payments" INNER JOIN "invoices" ON "payments"."invoice_id" = "invoices"."id" WHERE "invoices"."user_id" = 1 AND (date >= '2013-01-01' and date <= '2013-12-31')
```

The problem seems to be that I have a `date` field in my `invoices` as well as my `payments` table.

Yet I still don't know how to fix this error.

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  def number_of_payments_in(year)
    payments.where("payments.date >= ? and payments.date <= ?", "#{year}-01-01", "#{year}-12-31").count
  end 

end
```

---

```
class Payment < ActiveRecord::Base

  def self.search(year)
    if year
      where("date >= ? and date <= ?", "#{year}-01-01", "#{year}-12-31")
    end
  end

end
```

Can anybody help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*This answer may be a bit vague as it's not clear from your question which class the `self.search(year)` method is in, but let me know if this doesn't help and we can try and go further.*

My guess is that, unlike in the `number_of_payments_in` method, in the `self.search` method you haven't specified an appropriate table in the `where` call.

In `number_of_payments_in`, you specify `payments.date`, but in `self.search` you just use `date`. You said that you have a `date` field in your `invoices` as well as your `payments` table, so a join call across both tables will need every reference to `date` to be scoped by table.

Adding the appropriate table in front of `date` in `self.search` (as you have done in `number_of_payments_in`) may solve the problem.